# Calling a form in a JSP page in another JSP page div through javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe, call, spring-tool-suite

I am currently working on Spring tool Suite. And I have the following project structure.

[image: Project Structure]

I am trying to display the form that I have created in my *tableSelectForm.jsp* in a properties panel div that I have in my *veditor.jsp* view. I am trying to append the form by creating an iframe through javascript from the *veditor.js* script that I have under resources/js/taro/Customscripts and set the link to the *tabelSelectForm.jsp* and then append the iframe to the div in the *veditor.jsp*.

**tabelSelectForm.jsp**

```html
<html>
<head>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="tabelSelectForm">
 <fieldset>

</head>

<body>
 <!-- Form Name -->
 <legend>Table Selection</legend>
 
 <!-- Select Basic -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-6 control-label"> Select a Table out of the options to start querying from that table</label>
   <br>
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="streamSelect">Table</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <select id="streamSelect" name="streamSelect" class="form-control">
       <option value="voidopt">Select an option</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Button (Double) -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tableFormConfirmButton">Confirm</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <button id="tableFormConfirmButton" name="tableFormConfirmButton" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
     <button id="tableFormCancelButton" name="tableFormCancelButton" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**veditor.jsp**

```
...  
<script src="resources/js/taro/Customscripts/veditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
 <!--Container/Canvas-->

 <div id="container" class="container">
 </div>

 <div style="float: left" class="property" id="propertypane">
     <h1 class="toolbox-titlex" id="toolbox-titlex">Properties</h1>
     <div class="panel"  id="lot"></div>
 </div>
```

**veditor.js**

```js
...
function callTableForm(newAgent, i, e, mouseTop, mouseLeft,elemType)
    {
     $(".property").show(); 
     
     $(".property").show(); 
      
     var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
     iframe.frameBorder=0;
     iframe.width="inherit";
     iframe.height="inherit";
     iframe.id="randomid";
     document.getElementById("lot").appendChild(iframe);                
    
     $("property").show();
     $(".toolbox-titlex").show();
        $(".panel").show();
     $( "#randomid" ).load( "/tableSelectForm.jsp" );
    
    }
```

I am currently getting an output as shown here. Under the ***properties*** panel, I showld be able to display the form in *tableSelectForm.jsp*.

> I doubt that I am encountering this error due to the incorrect link that I've set in the iframe as ***var link = "/tableSelectForm.jsp"*** in my *veditor.js*

This is the error that I am encountering.

[image: Error]

And this is the Project structure along with the modified veditor.js script function.

[image: Path]

I would really appreciate a solution to change this path so that I could diplay the form under the properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is will you need [jquery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), this is a better solution than using iframes.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "/your_jsp_page_html_conten.jsp" );
```

Comment: I did modify as you've mentioned but the page is not loading. I sincerely doubt the path that I've provided keeps affecting this. Could you please suggest the correct path in which I should call the jsp page from the javascript. [The Javascript and Project Structure](http://i.imgur.com/a9zAPRC.png). And this is the error that I'm getting->[Error](http://i.imgur.com/5kVHlqL.png)

Comment: sorry, but this only a demo, i'm not coding for you.